# How are the words on review audits determined?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, edits, review-audits

I've gotten quite a few review audits while reviewing suggested edits lately, and I was wondering, How are the words used determined?

I know they're supposed to be easy to spot and obviously nonsense, but still I've seen many different words/phrases used. Is it completely random, or is there like a method to determine what's going to be used based on the tags/question?

Comment: As explained in the linked answer: *super simple model (basically a Porter Stemmer + Markov Chains) of a few thousand posts per-site, and using that to create "looks OK at a glance, but deeply flawed" audit edits. Thus "involve boy code machines".*